# I got this error, while writing an equation

Tags: math-mode

```
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Gesamtbeschäftigungsrente} &= \text{Beschäftigungsrente pro Stunde $\times$ erwartete Stunden der verlorenen Arbeitszeit} \\
&= \text{$4 pro Stunde $\mal$ 1.540 Stunden} \\
&= \$6,160
\end{align*}
$$
```

Comment: Start by removing the `$$` that surround the `align*` environment. Also, how is `\mal` defined?

Comment: In general `$$` shouldn't be used in LaTeX to start displayed maths ever. Also the `$` used in the fourth line of your small code block contains three `$` inside `\text`, that is bound to be wrong (I'd guess the first is the wrong one and should've been `\$` instead). Also the comma in the next line is inconsistent to the decimal dot used in the other line, and will give wrong spacing as you're using it. I suggest you take a look at `siunitx` and use it to typeset numbers and numbers with units (or currencies).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{Gesamtbeschäftigungsrente}
  &= \text{Beschäftigungsrente pro Stunde} \\
  &\quad\times \text{erwartete Stunden der verlorenen Arbeitszeit} \\
  &= \$\,4\,\text{pro Stunde} \times 1.540\,\text{Stunden} \\
  &= \$\,6.160
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```